# Getting files from other folders in android

Tags: android, directory

I want to make an array of specific types of files with .txt that are found in all android folders.

I am bit off I need to loop through all folders then create a list out of all the items found with the file name of ".txt".

My question is what method do I need to start from the top of all the folders? Also I need a method to open a specific folder(So I can loop through the FileNameFilter method).

Also I don't mind any recommendation on how to do this kind of method.

```
public String getFile(int position){
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();//This is incorrect it just goes to it's current environment it's folder found for this application.
    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {

        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return !filename.endsWith(".txt");
        }

    };
    ArrayList<File> items = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(root.listFiles(filter)));
    String returned = items.get(position).toString();
    return returned;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a recursive method that will loop through a folder and, for each child : if the child is a folder, call itself with the child as parameter. If the child is a file, check its name and add it if needed.

You can do something like

```
public void findAllFilesWithExtension( File dir, String extension, List<File> listFiles )   {
   List<File> listChildren = Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles());
   for( File child : listChildren ) {
      if( child.isDirectory() ) {
         findAllFilesWithExtension( child, extension, listFiles );
      } else if( child.getName().endsWith( extension ) ) {
        listFiles.add( child );
      } //else
   } //for
}//met
```

And call it first on your root directory.

Comment: My pleasure. Oh, and I wouldn't mind if you accept the answer ;)

Comment: You sir is a completely genius. If only I had 1% of your powa.